# Azure storage account blobs with https and custom domain

Tags: azure

I am currently architecting a new large enterprise e-commerce application and one of the requirements is https and custom domain for blobs in Azure.

My understanding is that this is not possible.

I would like to know:

1. Why?
2. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Both https and custom domain names are supported. If you're talking about combining the two... while I'm not positive, the combination of the two might not be available. You should edit your question to clarify. And if that _is_ your question... nobody here would be able to provide a "why" to a feature inclusion or exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSL with the default URL, or you can have a custom domain without SSL. You can't have both.

As to why, I have no idea but you can see [this uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3007732-make-it-possible-to-use-ssl-on-blob-storage-using) item for many other who want it.